# Извлечение нескольких записей из таблицы MySQL в PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте. Есть `MySQL` таблица, содержащая два поля - `id` и `text`. Поле `id` у каждых 5-6 элементов одно, `text` разное. Необходимо взять первые элемент с нужным `id` и вставить его в определенный кусок кода, а затем взять второй элемент с этим же `id` и вставить его в другой кусочек кода. 
Вытащил первые два элемента, дальше сделал так: `$row_images=mysql_fetch_array($result_images)`. Не получается достать первый и второй элемент методом `$row_images['text'][1]` или `['text'][2]`, так же не получается сделать аналогичное через `while($row_images=mysql_fetch_array($result_images)){}`. В общем, два элемента с одной строкой нужно поместить в разные переменные. Как можно реализовать подобное? 
Заранее спасибо за ответы.

Comment: Почему не получается? Приведите точно ваш код.

Comment: [depricated](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-connect.php)

    Данное расширение устарело, начиная с версии PHP 5.5.0, и будет 
    удалено в будущем. Используйте вместо него MySQLi или PDO_MySQL. 
    Смотрите также инструкцию MySQL: выбор API и соответствующий FAQ 
    для получения более подробной информации. Альтернативы для данной 
    функции:

[mysqli_connect()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysqli-connect.php)

[PDO::__construct()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdo.construct.php)

Comment: уже удалили)

Answer (score 3):

Расширение mysql устарело и исключено из новой версии PHP 7. Лучше всего воспользоваться расширением PDO

```
<?php
  try {
    $pdo = new PDO(
      'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test',
      'root',
      '',
      [PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION]);

    $query = "SELECT
                `text`
              FROM
                tbl
              WHERE
                id = :id";
    $tbl = $pdo->prepare($query);
    $tbl->execute(['id' => 3]);

    $row_images = $tbl->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($row_images);
    echo "</pre>";
  } catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Ошибка выполнения запроса: " . $e->getMessage();
  }
```

При помощи метода `fetchAll()` вы сможете извлечь все записи, возвращаемые запросом, указав в качестве первого параметра константу `PDO::FETCH_COLUMN` вы упростите результирующий массив до состояния

```
Array
(
    [0] => Первая запись
    [1] => Вторая запись
    ...
    [5] => Шестая запись
)
```

Далее вы сможете заменить значения, ориентируясь на порядок в массиве. При необходимости, задать сортировку элементов можно на уровне SQL-запроса, при помощи конструкции `ORDER BY`.