# Вывод значения, которое повторяется большее количество раз

Tags: mysql

Возникла потребность извлекать из БД значение, которое повторилось большее количество раз.
Пробовал разные варианты, но что-то делаю не то.

Пример:
Колонка с числами `8 1 2 6 8 5 1 8` - нужно выводить число 8.

Comment: ну и что у вас получилось?

Comment: сейчас попробую

Comment: Код нескольких неудачных попыток/вариантов стоит добавить в вопрос.

Comment: А если вопрос решен ответом ниже? нужно код в вопрос вставлять?

Comment: @100РОЖЬ нет, особого смысла тогда уже нет. Единственное: если вас полностью устраивает ответ на SQL, без PHP (несмотря на какие-то "запарки"), то из вопроса стоит убрать метки _php_ и _pdo_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В этом случае обычно прибегают к подсчету количества значений при помощи функции `COUNT()` и последующей сортировке при помощи `ORDER BY`

```
SELECT
  number
FROM
  tbl
GROUP BY
  number
ORDER BY
  COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, вопрос решен так как следует, а выводить в PHP что следует? В SQL проверил, все отлично, в PHP сделал print_r, не вывело ничего, хотя может моя запарка

Comment: @100РОЖЬ, лучше тогда задать новый вопрос или воспользоваться уже готовым ответом, например, пример вывода есть тут http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/231280